# installing any sdk platform for android studio takes very long time

Tags: android-studio

I totally beginner in regards to android apps and android studio and I am trying to learn Kotlin and for that I installed Android studio on Ubuntu 18.04 but when trying to install any sdk platform it takes very very long time to complete installing ( the window indicate "installing XXXX" ) is there any way to speed up the installing?
for example Installing Android SDK Platform 24 takes too long

My laptop specs:

core i7

8GB RAM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting set up with Android Studio can take a while, usually the download takes the longest time. Expect to download 1-2 GB. You definitely don't need all the SDK platforms, only the latest (currently 28), and you don't need the NDK platform either (unless you're writing in C/C++, which if you're new to Android development is unlikely). You can also avoid downloading an emulator image by just running your app on a real device.

Try going for the minimum amount of things you need to install to get a basic "Hello World!" app running, Android Studio will prompt you if you *need* to download anything else.

It could also be that your computer is struggling with its memory limits; 8GB of RAM can be tight if you have other programs running on your laptop as IDEs tend to be pretty heavy. Consider upgrading your RAM if you're serious about Android development, 16GB is usually plenty.

Comment: It no joke takes forever for this. I have 2 x 2.90GHz Processors each having 6 cores each and 64GB of memory on absurdly fast internet that takes seconds to download most things. Even with that Android Studio just drags in the dirt when updating the SDK, it takes like an hour to download and install platform components. It's been that way since the beginning, I've never seen The SDK Manager anything but painstakingly slow since way back in the early days of Android. Why is it so.... slow!